# java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, formatting

I have to round up final number by number of decimal places from user input.

Like this:

```
static String format(double var, double decimalPlaces) {
        return String.format("%." + decimalPlaces + "f%n", var);
    }

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
double s1,s2,sou,des;
s1 = s.nextDouble();
s2 = s.nextDouble();
des = s.nextDouble();
sou = s1 + s2;
System.out.printf(format(sou, des));
```

But on the line with:

```
return String.format("%." + decimalPlaces + "f%n", var);
```

It returns this error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'**

I looked up that formatting, but everyone had that like I had and also used double with variables. So now I have no idea where's the problem.

Any idea? THX

Comment: there is an extra `.`, which comes into the string from your `double` variable  ...try: `... + (int) decimalPlaces + ...` ..and better: `int des = s.nextInt(); .... String format(double var, int decimalPlaces)`

Answer (score 3):

`decimalPlaces` is not supposed to have such type as `double`, right?
You can't pass something like `%.2.71f`, because... because what do you want to expect then?

Shortly speaking, you need to pass integer value.

This is okay :

```java
String.format("%." + 3 + "f%n", var);
```

However this does not work (i.e. the same exception is thrown) :

```java
String.format("%." + 3.14 + "f%n", var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype of `deciamlValues` to `int`

```
    static String format(double var, int decimalPlaces) {
        return String.format("%." + decimalPlaces + "f%n", var);
    }
```

You may also use `NumberFormat` for this, then you don't need to write separate method for formatting.

```
        sou = s1 + s2;

        NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
        System.out.printf(df.format(sou));
```